# Firebase: setting additional user properties

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, database-design, firebase-authentication

I'd like to add a property to a Firebase user object. The [user documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users) says that I can only store additional properties using the Firebase real time database.

I am unsure on **how this can works** in practice.

What does the following mean in practice?

> You cannot add other properties to the Firebase User object directly;
>   instead, you can store the additional properties in your Firebase
>   Realtime Database.

I interpret it as following:

"you cannot modify properties of a **[FIRUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user#instance-method-summary)** object but you can combine this with additional objects"

I found the **set** function [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) which I interpet in this way:

```
  var userRef = ref.child("users");
  userRef.set({
    newfield: "value"
  });
```

Is this a sensible approach?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're almost there. In the legacy Firebase documentation, we had a section on [storing such additional user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing).

The key is to store the additional information under the user's `uid`:

```
    let newUser = [
        "provider": authData.provider,
        "displayName": authData.providerData["displayName"] as? NSString as? String
    ]
    // Create a child path with a key set to the uid underneath the "users" node
    // This creates a URL path like the following:
    //  - https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/users/<uid>
    ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
       .childByAppendingPath(authData.uid).setValue(newUser)
```

I've added a note that we should add this information in the new documentation too. We just need to find a good spot for it.

Comment: So the "users" node does not exist by default, unless created like this correct?  I agree this should be in the new docs. Would have saved me 2 days of confusion. :)

Comment: Im really confused too, im trying to achieve the exact dame thing however bring in an additional field upon registration for a zip/post code and save it somewhere but the docs lead me to believe this isn't possible?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) documentation,

> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user accounts. [...] User roles can be defined for the following common cases:
>
> - Add an additional identifier on a user. For example, a Firebase user could map to a different UID in another system.
>
> [...] Custom claims payload must not exceed 1000 bytes.

However, do this only for authentication-related user data, not for general profile information, per the [Best Practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#best_practices_for_custom_claims):

> Custom claims are only used to provide access control. They are not designed to store additional data (such as profile and other custom data). While this may seem like a convenient mechanism to do so, it is strongly discouraged as these claims are stored in the ID token and could cause performance issues because all authenticated requests always contain a Firebase ID token corresponding to the signed in user.
>
> Use custom claims to store data for controlling user access only. All other data should be stored separately via the real-time database or other server side storage.