# How to get user details in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to load comments from my firebase app into app

[image]

I have this structure
[image]

Now I want to extract details of user: (profile picture and username) with the id highlighted in the image.

For comments I could do something like this

```
DatabaseReference commentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("comments").child(video.id);
```

But I couldn't find a clue on getting user details. Can you help me?

Comment: great, and what did u try?

Comment: For comments I could do something like this
 DatabaseReference commentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("comments").child(video.id);

But I couldn't find a clue on getting user details.

Comment: So do you already know how to get the user id? Do you have the user info stored in any branch of your database?

Comment: Firebase Authentication doesn't have an API to query the list of users, not does it automatically store user information in the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties