# How to create a new user in Firebase with Username, Email and Password?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase. I want to create a new user in Firebase with Username,
Email and Password. I am trying to create it using Firebase's createUser() method. How can i add Username while create a new user, Here is the code I am using.

```
mFirebaseRef.createUser(Email, Password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<java.util.Map<String, Object>>() {
                    public void onSuccess(java.util.Map result) {
                        System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                    }
                    public void onError(com.firebase.client.FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        System.err.println("Error while creating user " + firebaseError);
                    }
                });
```

Using this code can create a user. I can see the user email which i used for signup.

Comment: You seem to be using the legacy Firebase SDK. An email+password user there, literally consists of those two pieces of information: an email address and a password. You'll have to keep the additional properties elsewhere, such as in the Firebase Database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a username, you can call [`updateProfile`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updateProfile(com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest)) in the [`FirebaseUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) class by passing in a [`UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder). There you can `setDisplayName`.

Comment: That works for the Firebase 3.x SDK, but OP seems to be using version 2.x.