# Firebase - Adding properties to authenticated user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

What is the best way to add properties to a FirebaseUser?

Is there a way to add to the FirebaseUser object?

Or do we need to create a separate /users/ tree in Firebase with each nodes key (for each user) as the users FirebaseUser.getUid() key ?

Comment: There is no API in Firebase Authentication to store custom properties for a user. The common solution is indeed to keep a list of users in the Firebase Database under a `/users/<user.uid>` nodes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties