# Firebase Auth: Properties of User Object

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase, and have seen - from the docs -  that the authenticated user has properties: `email`, `displayName`, `photoUrl`, `uid`.

1. Are there any other properties of this object?
2. Can one add properties to this object, for example, `user_role`?

Comment: 2) No, you can't add your own properties to the Firebase Authentication user profile. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties

Comment: For user_role, you have to use custom auth and add custom claims: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens