# Angular2 Firebase Set User Custom Propertise

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular2-routing

I've been trying to set user custom properties or attributes using `auth.updateProfile` method but it only save `displayName` property because it's mentioned in its [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) :

```
this.af.auth.createUser({
   email: formData.value.email,
   password: formData.value.password,
}).then((user) => {
   let userProfile = formData.value;
   userProfile.role = AuthService.ROLE_PATIENT;
   userProfile.displayName = `${formData.value.firstName} ${formData.value.lastName}`;
   user.auth.updateProfile(userProfile).then(function(){
   this.router.navigate(['/']);  
});
```

Now Problem how can i set custom properties of the user so i can get them in `FirebaseAuthState`

Question: Why i need to save custom properties with each user?

Answer: Because i'm working with [Auth Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) to activate a particular route using `role` property which is saved in the database example:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    //Currently I'm using this which only check that user is logged in or not
    return this.auth
      .take(1)
      .map((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => !!authState)
      .do(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      });   
  }
```

But i want one more check to validate the user has the role of patient which i've saved while creating the user above eg: 
 `return user.role == 'patient'`

Comment: The Firebase console and Google Cloud console use the same underlying roles and permissions. At a high-level, these are owner, editor, and viewer.

Comment: which will not solve my problem, can you have a proper solution or theory to role specific thing ?

Comment: Can't you just combine them in the do?

Answer (score 1):

The existing identity providers in Firebase Authentication have no way to add custom properties. If you want to add custom properties, you will either have to implement a custom identify provider (see [minting custom tokens in a trusted process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and [signing in with a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase)) OR do a [client-side look-up of the additional information from an alternate data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties) (such as the Firebase Database).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    //Currently I'm using this which only check that user is logged in or not
    return this.auth
      .take(1)
      .map((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => {

        return this.af.database.list('/path/to/account').first().map((account: IAccount) => {

          if (authState && account.role === 'patient') {
            return true;
          }
          else {
            return this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

It's quite far-fetched but it might just work. Or help you along the way to find an answer.