# Authentication firebase + Database firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I use  authentication firebase to login and logout(by email/password).
Now I would like to add information in this user(Name, age,...) ? How to do it? Please help me . Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415863/firebase-setting-additional-user-properties/37420701#37420701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you log in the user , you can update his info using this method:

```
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
mFirebaseUser.updateProfile(new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Someone")
        .setPhotoUri(someImageUri)
        .build());
```

For additional fields you would have to create entries in the Realtime DB.

Comment: It adds the info into the internal firebase profile system (aka. the FirebaseUser) , the only limitation is you can only add name and photo.

Comment: oh, how to get id of  from authentication to add new Node in database ? after that i can add Name,age,image, description . I am sorry if you don't understand because I am new android and my english is not good :)

Comment: mFirebaseUser.getUid()